# How to insert two rows when a special condition is met using SQL?

Tags: sql, psql

Basically I have this situation:

For each row in a table, I have to take the value of one of the columns and insert it into a new table.

It is a simple query:

```
SELECT val
INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

However, I have  a problem. On certain scenarios, I would like to insert TWO rows for the same entry.

I can achieve it using the following three queries:

```
SELECT 'val'
INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE NOT SPECIAL_CONDITION;

SELECT 'special_val1'
INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE SPECIAL_CONDITION;

SELECT 'special_val2'
INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE SPECIAL_CONDITION;
```

But is there any way to do this using a single one?

I thought of something like this (which may not work because I haven't tested it):

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE 
( 
    (SELECT 'val' FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE NOT CONDITION)

    UNION

    (SELECT 'val1' FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE CONDITION)

    UNION

    (SELECT 'val2' FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE CONDITION)
)
```

But in the end verbosity is OK if it ends up being more efficient. 
So is there a more efficient way of doing this with a single query?

Comment: . . Do you really intend the "psql" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
INTO NEW_TABLE 
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN condition THEN 'val1' ELSE 'val' END) as val
      FROM SOURCE_TABLE
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'val2'
      FROM SOURCE_TABLE
      WHERE CONDITION
     ) t;
```